# Module not found when trying to import files into Custom Django commands

Tags: python, django, database

**Background**

I'm new to Django and trying to set up a Django database with react front end for a trading card game database.

I'm using a custom command in Django to pull cards from MTG's API and then using a serializer to save the data I'm pulling.

**Problem**

When I try to run the custom command it fails because my program can't seem to find my serializer module.

I have tried to specify the path with sys, but it doesn't seem to work and I believe all my modules have an __ init __.py so they can be recognized as modules. I'm definitely willing to admit I did these things incorrectly, however.

**The exact error**: *ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'MTG_hoard.api'*

Here is a snapshot of my project directory...

[image]

Here is how I'm importing the serializer...

[image]

**Additional information**

I'm basing my project on another github project FearChar/project-4-django-app.

This is how I'm importing my apps in settings.py

[image]

Comment: The app is named `api` and the import should be `from api.serializers import ...`, your imports will be relative to the directory containing `manage.py`

Comment: Thank you that seems to fix the problem. I was going to do that earlier, but for some reason, it highlighted my change as red so I thought it was incorrect. If you post your solution I will select it as the correct answer.